# How can I allow lists to appear on odd page?

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright]{mwrep}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2cm,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage[section]{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoflistings

\chapter{c1}
\lipsum
\begin{figure}
.
\label{f1}
\caption{figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\begin{listing}
.
\label{l1}
\caption{listing}
\end{listing}

\chapter{c2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

In this MWE I want to start each chapter at even page. I want to make an exception for `\listoffigures` and `\listoflistings`. How can I do that?

Comment: Please see my updated improved answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the `twoside` and `openright` class options. You can then locally `\let` `\cleardoublepage` to be `\clearpage` for the lists (so they can start on any page) and then redefine `\cleardoublepage` to make sure every subsequent chapter will begin in an even numbered page:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{mwrep}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoflistings
\endgroup
\makeatletter

\renewcommand*\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside
  \ifodd\c@page \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}%
  \newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\lipsum

\chapter{Test Chapter Three}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

And the resulting ToC:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Gonzalo!
To avoid the redefinition of `\cleardoublepage` you can use brackets to change the definition just temporary:

```
{\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage\listoffigures}
{\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage\chapter{MyChapter}}
```